# jQuery Ajax on success is VERY slow

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a list with 1000 test items, each Item contains 8 propetys. I have a problem with loading time.

When i load the page i run GetListOfTestItems().
The time it takes before it hit return in getTestItems() is under 0.56 seconds.
Loading time of whole page is 10.78 seconds. 
Tested in different browsers with same result
After ajax hit success it loads right away, so i think extra 10 secnds comes from, when server send result back to ajax. How to imporove loading time?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<TestItem> getTestItems()
    {
        List<TestItem> list = service.getTestItems();

        return list;
    }




function GetListOfTestItems() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'UserProfile.aspx/getTestItems',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: OnAjaxError,
        success: addAnsweredQuestions

    });

}

}
```

Comment: There's not much you can do in JavaScript to speed up your load time. The problem is probably entirely in the server-side script.

Comment: But i checked time which it takes to hit return on server side its under 1 second.... what could it be?:S

Comment: You're asking us to judge the efficiency of your entire page based on one snippet of code, which is already optimized. We can't answer your question without pouring over your entire codebase. You need to try to narrow down the cause of the slowdown yourself before coming to us.

Comment: I narrowed down allready as much as i could.. i started yesterday with 30 sec of loading time, now im down to 10...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long does it take until the addAnsweredQuestions is first called? it could be the ajax call is a red herring and something else on the page is slowing things down.

Comment: its takes 10 seconds as soon as it hit loadading takes under 1 sec

Comment: How about trying returning a simple canned response with a single item with one property from the server? if that loads faster, it could point to the parsing of the JSON taking longer, though I would be surprised.

Comment: it takes 208ms with 1 single item

Comment: There you go - apparently the objects you are returning are very large somehow - have you tried logging the json from the server side before returning it to make sure you aren't somehow including a much larger response or object graph than you are intending?

Comment: So even if propertys are empty they still take time to load? (im quite new to using ajax)

Comment: Both the size of the response and the complexity of the objects will influence perceived load time, first in the time to download the response, second, to parse the json. I'm still confused as to what could possibly cause the perceived response time to be at 10 seconds - which is why I thought it might be some accidentally huge or complex json response - a list of 10 objects with a few properties each shouldn't take that long at all.

Comment: it is complexity, just tested it by removing a 1 big property, and loading time reduced to 5 sec. now i need to find an other way to load this object.